# How to determine if popup loads successfully?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am integrating the login with Paypal feature, my problem is I want to know if Paypal's end point address is not working

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#paypalButton').click(function () {
            var state = "@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString())";
            var url = "@Model.PaypalLoginPopupAuthorizationEndPointUrl"+state;
            url = url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
            var width = 400;
            var height = 500;
            var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
            var top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
            window.open(url, 'PaypalLoginPopup', 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=' + left + ',top=' + top); 
        });
    });
```

How can I know if the url is not working **IT MEANS THE PAYPAL END POINT IS DOWN** , can I call back the actual parent page if the url is not working. I have never done this before, so I dont know if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

If it opens in a new browser window, there would be no way to check it, unless you do an AJAX request beforehand and ensure the page returns something